# How to unit test private variable?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class for products (`MyProduct`) and then another class (`ProductAnalyzer`) for performing various options on a collection of products.

I want to do unit testing on these classes. Specifically, testing if product is X days old or older.

There is already a function called `ProductAnalyzer.tenDaysOld()` that will do this. As long as instances of `MyProduct` are in the  `ProductAnalyzer` collection, it will do the calculation.

In order to run tests, I need a way to somehow modify timestamps on MyProduct instances so they are older than 10 days. Or perhaps modify `tenDaysOld()`. Either way, I'm guessing they'll need to be mocked.

In `MyProduct`, `productCreated` is timestamped and private. I'd like to keep it that way but that means it can't be tested. If I modify it to public, I can test it but then I'm changing the code base just for testing purposes, which has nothing to do with actual functionality in production (isn't that bad practice?).

Any suggestions how I can approach this?

Below are simplified versions of the classes with relevant code shown.

```
class MyProduct: NSObject {
    private var productCreated:Date

    init(){
        productCreated = Date()
    }
}

class ProductAnalyzer {
    static var products:[InventoryItem] = []
    static func tenDaysOld() {
        let tenDays = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day, value: 10, to: Date())

        let oldProducts = ProductAnalyzer.products.filter({  $0.dateAdded.compare(tenDays!) == .orderedDescending })

    }
}
```

Comment: A few off the top of my head, inject the `Date` in the initializer of `MyProduct`, giving you control of what date gets passed in. Or create a protocol and mock it. Assigning the mock objects to the `products` property in the unit tests. Then check to make sure the right products get filtered out.

Comment: How about mocking NSCalendar.current.date ? To simulate a future date ?

Comment: @rad: how would the objects know about it. To JustinM's point, you probably have to still inject.

Comment: If it's possible you will inject a function instead of using directly NSCalendar... and for your test you will have a kind of time traveling fake implementation. Somewhere you need to inject dates to be able to reproduce your scenario ^^